Error uploading an image with Instagram Graph API (Python script)
I keep getting this error, my image is in 1080X1350 resolution and in jpg format, I have tried changing the resolution and the format of the image but it still gives me the same error.
Here is the error:
PS C:\Jann\Python Scripts> & C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Jann/Python Scripts/InstaPoster.py"
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The image format is not supported.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 36001,
        "error_subcode": 2207005,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Unsupported format",
        "error_user_msg": "The image format unknown is not supported.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AViMHsnXgFXo7lwnbwockUh"
    }
}

Here is my code:
import requests
import json

# Your access token with necessary permissions
access_token = 'xxx'

# Instagram User ID of the account you want to post to
user_id = '17841442656991877'
image_url = 'https://ibb.co/WzfJmWW'
caption = 'Uploaded with Instagram Graph API.'

# Step 1: Create Media Container
media_creation_url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{user_id}/media'
media_params = dict()
media_params['media_type'] = 'IMAGE'
media_params['image_url'] = image_url
media_params['caption'] = caption
media_params['access_token'] = access_token


# Make a POST request to create a media container
response = requests.post(media_creation_url, media_params)
data = json.loads(response.content)
data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

# Extract media ID from the response
#media_id = data['id']
print(data)

# Step 2: Publish Media
'''media_publish_url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{media_id}/media_publish?access_token={access_token}'

# Make a POST request to publish the media
media_publish_response = requests.post(media_publish_url)

# Check if media publishing was successful
if media_publish_response.status_code == 200:
    print("Media publish successful!")
else:
    print("Failed to publish media:", media_publish_response.text)'''


please post the complete traceback of the error, properly formatted. How do you know the image is jpg?

@Elerium115 it's properly formatted now. here's the image link. when you hover on the download button, it shows the image resolution and the format (which is in jpg).

The error is a nice formatted dictionary? I would have expected some console error. Well I don't know how to reproduce your error and get this dictionary missing a closing bracket. Are you sure this is the exact error you are getting verbatim?

@Elerium115 Sorry bout that, i forgot that ive commented out Step 2 & below and added print(data) to see if im getting the media_id (which i need to publish the photo) and this is the output it gives me (see post) from the print(data).

Bit of that's the content of data, then when you do media_id = data['id'] should give a Keyerrpr since data doesn't have a key named id

@Elerium115 yeah thats the problem, I need the id to publish it. Any idea how?

The problem is that I don't understand how the code you posted prints anything without a print statement and how it doesn't crash since you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist. Are you absolutely sure that the code you posted in your question is exactly the one you are executing? Because if what you posted is different than what you are executing then your question is not reproducible and invalid. Ina comment you mention something you forgot but I don't see any edits in your question reflecting that.

@Elerium115 There edited in the code.

image_url doesn't point to a JPG image, it points to a url (which happens to contain an image amongst other things), hence the error about the format of the image not recognized (because it's not an image)
